# Unix- smallest value in column

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a txt file which is just three columns of numbers separated by space. I need to use "sort" to display the smallest value of column 3 and only that value.

I tried

sort -k3 file.txt|head -1

but it shows the first value of all three columns.

Comment: `sort ... | head ..| cut -d" " -f3` (maybe). But not the best solution. maybe `sort ... | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'` . Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! The second one worked!

Comment: Glad that helped. For simple text processing problems like this, it will be worth your time to read/test/experiment your way thru the [Grymoire's Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's expected. `sort -k3 file.txt | head -1` says "show me the first line of output"

Use just plain `sort -k3 file.txt | head` to get the first 10 lines.

What were you expecting or wanting?

In response to the comment: No worries! We're all beginners at the beginning :-)

`sort -r file.txt` will sort in reverse order, and as @shellter says, `sort -r -k3 file.txt | awk 'NR==1{print $3}` will print the third value on the first line.

Comment: Im Sorry, I really just started learning how to use UNIX. I want to sort the third Column so i have the largest number first and then i want to display that number.